# “ImportError: No module named scipy” after installing the scipy package

Tags: python, scipy

I need help with the scipy Python module. I installed it, but when I try to import it, I get an error (no module named scipy). Why?

Here's the output from my Python interpreter:

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:08:48) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import scipy

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import scipy
ImportError: No module named scipy
```

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: i installed in here "https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scipy/0.15.1"  and i install all of dependention excapt pyzmq.

Comment: I would do `which -a python`, if you see more than one then you have multiple installs which can cause similar  problems because pip installs for one and you use another

Comment: you are right. i installed a few pyzmq.