# python - ImportError: No module named scipy on Mac

Tags: python, pip, homebrew

It's been so hard to find solution for this problem.

I've been reading on the internet and found this questions on Stackoverflow:

[Solution #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29223187/importerror-no-module-named-scipy-after-installing-the-scipy-package) and [Solution #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24808043/importerror-no-module-named-scipy) with no results.

When I use:

```
pip install scipy
```

It outputs

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scipy in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
```

Then I do

```
pip install scipy --updrage
```

And it outputs

```
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 
'/var/folders/y3/r_j97_g91494mm7r9th0zycm0000gn/T/pip-paR57c-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy-1.8.0rc1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

I even try to install using `port`:

```
sudo port install py27-numpy py27-scipy py27-matplotlib py27-ipython +notebook py27-pandas py27-sympy py27-nose
```

Same result, it says it's been installed but when I try to run my Python project, prints the same error.

Hope you guys can help me.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo pip reinstall scipy` or `sudo pip install -U scipy`

Comment: Outputs `ERROR: unknown command "reinstall" - maybe you meant "install"`

Comment: my bad! maybe `sudo pip uninstall scipy` then reinstall it

Comment: Outputs `The directory '/Users/alex/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.`

Comment: @Alex so, did you do that?

Comment: what @MattDMo said, `sudo -H pip uninstall scipy` then `sudo -H pip install scipy`

Comment: Also, why did you tag this `homebrew` when you're using MacPorts?

Comment: To get rid of the operation no permitted issue you can try `sudo pip install --user --upgrade scipy`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your issue may be how you are running your code - OS-X can have **both** the system python and a user python installation.

From the command prompt, (the same one that pip tells you that you already have scipy installed), try running your script, *which I will assume is called `your_script.py`* with:

```
python your_script.py
```

And it should work, however if you run:

```
your_script.py
```

it may not work.

I don't have a Mac to experiment on but you should do some reading on this issue online - [here](https://docs.python.org/3/using/mac.html)